# Error in send email (Mail) later laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

I use the instructions https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail
to send an email later than expected, but I get an error when I try to send it:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Only mailables may be queued. (View: ....
```

Please for help.
My methods to send:

```
 public static function sent_info_email_later ($data_f, $minuts) {
    $data = json_decode($data_f);
    $when = now()->addMinutes($minuts);

    return Mail::later($when,'emails.message', ['title' => $data->subject, 'body' => $data->body], function ($message) use ($data,  $when)
    {

        $message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'NETPlatform24');

        if(gettype($data->to) == 'array') {
            $dest_to = $data->to;
        } else {
            $dest_to = explode(', ', $data->to)[0];
        }


        $message->to($dest_to);

        $message->subject($data->subject);

        return true;

    });
}
```

and calling index.php

```
$data = json_encode(array('to' => 'my email', 'subject' => 'This email was send 1 min after run', 'body' => 'time now'.now().'<br> time send: '.now()->addMinutes(1))); 
                $send_mail = \App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Auth\Mail\MailController::sent_info_email_later($data, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code long time ago. I hope this will help to clarify. For each Cargo I send a email using queue.

```
<?php   
   public function mails_meeting($meeting, $group, $place, $date, $message, $user)
    {
        $subject = "meeting " . $group;

        $cargos = Cargo::where('comision_id', '=', $meeting->comision_id)->where('active', '=', '1')->get();
        foreach ($cargos as $cargo) {
            $mail_reciever = $cargo->asambleista->user->email;
            Mail::queue('correos.comision_mail', ['group' => $group, 'place' => $place,
                'date' => $date,  'message' => $message, 'user' => $user],
                function ($mail) use ($subject, $mail_reciever) {
                    $mail->from('siarcaf@gmail.com', 'Automatic mail system');
                    $mail->to($mail_reciever);
                    $mail->subject($subject);
                });
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

In your_app/config/mail.php .

```
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'stream' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

.env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=your_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=your_conf
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting (and [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#queueing-mail)) indicate that the second argument passed to the `later` method must be an instance of `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable`.

Where you currently have the string `'emails.message'`, you will need to replace this with an instance of `Mailable` that represents the email message that you're trying to send.

For example, create this file in `/app/Mail` (create the folder if it doesn't exist):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class InfoEmail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    public $subject;

    public $body;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($subject, $body)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        return $this->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'NETPlatform24')
            ->subject($this->subject)
            ->view('emails.message', ['title' => $this->subject, 'body' => $this->body]);
    }
}
```

This assumes that `'emails.message'` is the view file you intend to use for this email, located at `/resources/views/emails/message.blade.php` relative to your project's root. I'd actually recommend changing this to something a bit more descriptive.

You'll then need to change your `sent_info_email_later` method to something like this:

```php
public static function sent_info_email_later ($data_f, $minuts) {
    $data = json_decode($data_f);
    $when = now()->addMinutes($minuts);

    $recipients = is_array($data->to) ? $data->to : explode(', ', $data->to);
    $recipients = array_filter(array_map('trim', $recipients));
    $first_recipient = array_shift($recipients);

    return Mail::to($first_recipient)
               ->cc($recipients)
               ->later($when, new InfoEmail($data->subject, $data->body));
}
```

I've taken the liberty of tidying up your recipients by extracting out the first recipient for the `to` and moving the rest to `cc` as this may play better with more email service providers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have one more question, the later function does not work an email is sent immediately, how to fix it?

Comment: You’ll also need to make sure you’ve got your [queue configuration setup](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#introduction). By default, I believe the queue driver is `sync` which means nothing will be queued and all jobs will be sent synchronously.